# Pass date parameter to native query

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

A user can perform actions based on an occurrence value. When this value is equal to 'DAILY', I would like to retrieve all daily actions that have not been completed the last 24 hours.

The working SQL query:

```
SELECT distinct a.* FROM action as a LEFT OUTER JOIN history as h
ON a.id = h.action_id
AND h.user_id= <user> WHERE a.occurrence = 'DAILY' AND (h.id is NULL OR h.entry_date < TIMESTAMP 'yesterday')
```

The equivalent native query:

```
@Query(value = 
        "SELECT distinct a.* FROM action a "
        + "LEFT OUTER JOIN history h "
        + "ON a.id = h.action_id "
        + "AND h.user_id = :userId "
        + "WHERE a.occurrence='DAILY' AND (h.id IS NULL OR h.entry_date < :yesterday) ", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Action> findAllAvailableActions(@Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("yesterday") ZonedDateTime yesterday);
```

How it is called in my service :

```
ZonedDateTime today = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime yesterday = today.minus(1,ChronoUnit.DAYS);
Long userId = userDTO.getId();
List<Action> result = actionRepositoryCustom.findAllAvailableActions(userId, yesterday);
```

However, I do get the wrong results in my tests (actions that have already been completed are returned). I am afraid this is linked to the date parameter. The attribute entry_date is declared as ZoneDateTime in my entity. What am I doing wrong ?

> hibernate : 5.2.4

Comment: How entry_date is declared in the database?What type is entry_date in the database?Also the entry_date in the database it is saved in the UTC timezone?

Comment: entry_date is described as **timestamp without time zone** in my db. I do save it using the following syntax in Java:   `historyDTO.setEntryDate(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass a ZonedDateTime into a native SQL query. You need to convert it to Calendar:

```
@Query(value = 
    "SELECT distinct a.* FROM action a "
    + "LEFT OUTER JOIN history h "
    + "ON a.id = h.action_id "
    + "AND h.user_id = :userId "
    + "WHERE a.occurrence='DAILY' AND (h.id IS NULL OR h.entry_date < :yesterday)", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Action> findAllAvailableActions(@Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("yesterday") Calendar yesterday);
```

And you can convert your ZonedDateTime this way:

```
public Calendar convertToDatabaseColumn(ZonedDateTime entityAttribute) {
    if (entityAttribute == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(entityAttribute.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(entityAttribute.getZone()));
    return calendar;
}
```

This approach is described here: [link](http://outofrange.ru/2018/02/how-to-pass-a-zoneddatetime-into-native-sql-query-in-jpa/)

Comment: I am really impressed by the post you wrote (I suppose since I don't read russian :p) At the time I have faced the issue, as I couldn't solve it, I used a stored procedure instead, but indeed your solution looks much cleaner. I agree with the logic, I've tried it on another function and the results look correct.  Thanks @dimirsen

Comment: You are welcome! My English is well enough to answer quite complex questions :) I've happened to face the same issue recently and decided to share my solution.

Comment: Instead of Calendar, you can also use the local date part from the ZonedDateTime (toLocalDate()) if the time part is not important.