# How to select entity using ZonedDateTime from datebase with timestamp with time zone?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, repository, zoneddatetime

in application on spring boot I saved entity with zonedDateTime field.

```
@Entity
class User{
    public String name;
    public ZonedDateTime registred;
}
```

and used spring-repository for saving. I used oracle database and in User table - there is 3 columns - id, name, registred(timestamp with time zone)

I want to read this value by register date

```
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-04-20'T'15:15:00.000Z");
repository.findByDate(date);
```

but findByDate throws exception

My repository

```
@Repository
public interface RiskServiceEventRepository extends CrudRepository<RiskServiceEventRecord, String> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM SBDATASVCS.RISKSERVICEEVENTRECORD WHERE type=?1 AND save_date_time BETWEEN ?2 AND ?3", nativeQuery = true)
    List<RiskServiceEventRecord> findByRiskServiceTypeBetweenEventDateTime(String riskServiceType, ZonedDateTime start, ZonedDateTime end);
}
```

the error message is

> "could not prepare statement; SQL [SELECT * FROM User WHERE type=? AND
>   save_date_time=?]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare
>   statement }

Comment: Unless you explicitly need to store user-facing zone information (specifically, unless you're implementing calendaring), normalize everything to `Instant` for storage.

Comment: Do you have a usecase where you need to preserve/retrieve the zone? Else you could store/retrieve info in UTC format.

Comment: As the others have hinted, you can’t save a `ZonedDateTime`, such as 2020-05-02T03:03:27.044356-04:00[America/Montserrat], into a `timestamp with time zone` field and retrieve the same value back. The “with time zone” is false advertising. In most database engines a `timestamp with time zone` really just means a timestamp in UTC.

Comment: Seems I was wrong in your case, though. According to [this documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm) exactly in Orcale database a `timestamp with time zone` also includes a time zone offset and region, which should be what you need (I am letting my comment stand for users of other DB brands).

Comment: Faced a kind of similar issue but with a native query and came to know ZonedDateTime is not supported. Have a look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48923201/471467, saved my day